# Show a view with a hole

Tags: android

I'm trying to create a view as tutorial for my activity. I need to show only some text with a translucent background an leave a "hole" transparent to see the background button of the original activity. I can use a framelayout with two different sub-layout (the original one and the tutorial one) and I can set visible/invisible the tutorial layout. The problem is: I don't know how I can create a "hole" in the tutorial sub-layout. How can I do?

Comment: If you can explain through dummy design, it would be better.

Comment: @NoorNawaz I'm trying to do something similar: https://github.com/amlcurran/ShowcaseView

Answer (score 1):

For create a "hole" or circular view you need create a drawable

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval">

    <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />

</shape>
```

And create a imageview in the position and size that you want and set this drawable like background.

Also you can use #00000000 intead @android:color/transparent

Or use [TutorialView](https://github.com/itzikBraun/TutorialView) library on github

Comment: Ok but if I create an imageview with that bakground I see actually the translucent background of the linearlayout.

Comment: @greywolf82 I edit my answer, use #00000000 if transparent ins not fully transparent.

Comment: the problem is that I put this imageview inside a relativelayout or linearlayout which background is translucent. With your method the imageview creates a "hole" it's true but the hole background is the translucent relativelayout background!

Comment: For complete showcase you need draw your activity and redraw, you need use canvas for this, is better use a library for do this.

Comment: Your response is useless then

Comment: Not at all, use TutorialView Library, or show his code.

Answer (score 1):

background colors should transparent, opaque
I hope, it will work for you.

circle_background.xml file

```
<shape
 android:shape="ring"
 android:useLevel="true"
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <solid android:color="@color/blue_pressed" />
</shape>
```

view_background.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:background="@drawable/circle_background"
>
//add more views if u wanto
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: A linear layout with a ring as background?? How can I put the "hole" in the right position in this way?

Comment: You can customize circle_background drawables according to your need. You can make hole of that. And then you can use that drawable as background in your view.